# MySQL function to get list of Mondays

Tags: sql, mysql

What is the most efficient way to get a list of all of the unique Mondays from a date field?

When I'm not all that concerned about efficiency, I have done something like:

`DATE-weekday(DATE) + 1`. But now I need to compute this on a large dataset and I don't want my user wishing for a Rubik's cube because it is taking so long. :)

Yes, the field is indexed.

**EDIT:**
What I need is a list of all of the weeks that contain records. I am creating a payroll report where the user will select the week to filter the report.

Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ((DATE(`timStart`)-DAYOFWEEK(`timStart`))+2)
FROM `time` 
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Anyone have any improvement to suggest?

Comment: i dont know the answer bro but its "Rubik's Cube"

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough.

Comment: List of the weeks?  Pls provide an example of expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"unique mondays from a date field" should be as simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`date`) FROM `table` WHERE WEEKDAY(`date`)=0
```

"weeks in which we have date values" should be as simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(WEEK(`date`)) FROM `table` WHERE YEAR(`date`)=2010;

SELECT WEEK(now()),YEAR(now());

+-------------+-------------+
| WEEK(now()) | YEAR(now()) |
+-------------+-------------+
|          31 |        2010 | 
+-------------+-------------+
```

which will benefit you as well in your other payroll queries, using

```
WHERE WEEK(`date`)=31
```

Put your trust in mysql to handle things from there.

Comment: The reason that won't work is because it is possible that there may be records for a given week but none on Monday.

Comment: then just query for weeks, not mondays. in your program, find the monday belonging to the week. don't make things overly complex.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, the WEEK function. Sorry I wasn't clearer with my question.